# How to do this job without creating a new list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2}...}` a list `{z1,z2...}`, I want to create a new list `{{x1,w1},{x2,w2}...}`, where `wi=0.5` if `yi<zi` and `wi=-0.5` otherwise. I attack this problem by the following code. However, how to avoid creating a new list `lsNew`? I think it is a redundancy.

```
ls = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 5}};
v = {2, 7, 8};
lsNew = Transpose[Insert[Transpose[ls], v, 3]]
lsWanted={#[[1]], If[#[[2]] < #[[3]], 0.5, -0.5]} & /@ lsNew
```

Comment: no, i just want to compare v and ls directly using a pure function... I dont't know if there is a way to do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same idea as @eldo with a simpler `MapThread`:

```
MapThread[{#1[[1]], If[#1[[2]] < #2, 0.5, -0.5]} &, {ls, v}]
```

Comment: This is what I want, because this doesn't create a new list, but directly compare them.

Comment: @buzhidao This is one of those questions that will produce quite a few answers. There will probably be some much more interesting ones to come.

Answer (score 3):

```
{#[[1]], If[#[[2]] < #[[3]], 0.5, -0.5]} & /@ MapThread[Append, {ls, v}]
```

> {{1, -0.5}, {2, 0.5}, {1, 0.5}}

This should be very fast:

```
ls[[All, 2]] = Unitize[Last /@ ls - v] - 0.5

ls
```

> {{1, -0.5}, {2, 0.5}, {1, 0.5}}

Answer (score 2):

```
MapAt[If[# < 0, 0.5, -0.5] &, ls - Map[{0, #} &, v], {All, 2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{#[[1]], 0.5 - UnitStep[#[[2]] - v]}\[Transpose] &[ls\[Transpose]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you do not want to make new lists, and looking for something different to the other answers:

```
ls[[All, 2]] = Transpose[{ls[[All, 2]], v}] /. {{x_, y_} /; x < y :>0.5, {_, _} -> -0.5}
ls
```

Answer (score 2):

In the spirit of @MikeHoneychurch, without `If`:

```
Thread[{#1[[All, 1]], Thread[#1[[All, 2]] < #2]}] &[ls, v] /. {True :> 0.5, False :> -0.5}
```